# I am trying to get a result from function, but I have encountered some troubles! (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-function

I formed a function
`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION is_eligible(
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    second_name VARCHAR(50))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE insurance bool;
SELECT uni_health_insurance_ INTO insurance FROM student;
    IF insurance=0 THEN 
        RETURN 'no'; 
    ELSEIF insurance='1' THEN 
        RETURN 'yes';
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

`

I tried to get some results - unfortunately all I got are nulls despite having coded the values in the student table.
Where I did wrong?

Comment: you must add a where clause with name, also please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You have a digit 0 and a string `'1'`.  Which one is it?

Comment: Oh heck, I haven't seen it before - but yeah I wanted digits for tinyint

Answer (score 1):

You need add a WHERE clause to your query see sample

In your compare you have 0 and '1' is doesn't matter because MySQL will convert it automatically, but it is usually better stick to one

```
CREATE TABLe student (id int auto_increment PRIMARY key, first_name varchar(4)
  , second_name varchar(4),uni_health_insurance_ bool)
```

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES(NULL,'A','A', FAlse),(NULL,'B','B', TRUE)
```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_eligible(
    _first_name VARCHAR(50),
    _second_name VARCHAR(50))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE insurance bool;
SELECT uni_health_insurance_ INTO insurance FROM student
  WHERE first_name = _first_name  AND second_name = _second_name;

    IF insurance=0 THEN 
        RETURN 'no'; 
    ELSEIF insurance='1' THEN 
        RETURN 'yes';
    END IF;
END;
```

```
SELECT is_eligible('A','A')
```

| is_eligible('A','A') |
| --- |
| no |

```
SELECT is_eligible('B','B')
```

| is_eligible('B','B') |
| --- |
| yes |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tNh3cLW8)